# What is the dynamics of centrifugal force in non-inertial system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

I am trying to intergrate the centtifugal force and the integral of φ(dφ/dt)^2 appears in polar coordinates. Does anyboby know if i'm doing something wrong or if i'm not, does anyboby know the solution of the integral?

Comment: I assume t is time, but please clarify what is φ?

Comment: sorry i'm greek. φ is the angle of the circular movement. dφ/dt is the angular velocity (we symbolize it with ω)

Comment: So, according to your comment, this expression is an integral of an angle times an angular speed squared: $\int \varphi\omega^2 \, dt$? May I ask what connection this expression appears in?

Comment: ok... I integrated the centrifugal force to find its dynamic because we know that F=-gradV. when you do that appears a function c(φ). I'm trying to integrate this function in order to find V(total of centtifugal force) and i have to solve the integral ms[integral[(Rφ(dφ/dt)^2-L(dφ/dt)^2-2R(d^2(φ)/(dt)^2(dφ/dt)]dφ]

Comment: R:radiant
L:lenght of string

Comment: m:mass of the object
s: from polar coordinates

Comment: Please use MathJax to make your math readable.

Comment: You need to explain the problem and show more of your work. $\phi$ should probably not be appearing undifferentiated.